# Disabling browserAction for my extension on all tabs

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to add a "Disable" action in the context menu of my extension, to disable the extension until user decides to enable it back.

Problem: chrome.browserAction.disable only works for one tab.

How can I make it work for all existing and future tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not specify any `tabId` when calling `chrome.browserAction.disable`.

Instead of calling `chrome.browserAction.disable(tabId)`, use `chrome.browserAction.disable()`. That will disable the browserAction icon for all tabs. However, take into account that you will not be able to open the popup menu until you re-enable it.

Comment: I've tried that and could swear it didn't work. But I guess that was just my setup. Now I tried again and it works! Thank you!!